# How to get the column letter of a cell?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a cell of which I know the column number. I need to find out what is the corresponding letter using Apache POI.

```
String column_letter = newCellReference(cell).convertNumToColString(column_number);
```

This is what I've tried but it's not working.

Comment: What's wrong with calling [getCellRefParts](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#getCellRefParts--) on the cell reference and grabbing the column part out?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[CellReference.convertNumToColString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertNumToColString-int-) is a `static` method. So no `new CellReference` object needed. And it needs the numeric column index from the `cell`which can be get via  [Cell.getColumnIndex](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getColumnIndex--).

So

```
String column_letter = CellReference.convertNumToColString(cell.getColumnIndex());
```